# Optimize.py: issue with stepsize of fmin_bfgs in new scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to optimize a MLE function using `fmin_bfgs`, and logistic regression algorithm. There's no problem in convergence using the older version (scipy 0.10). However when using newer version 0.15 the optimizer crashes with

```
warning: "Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss”
```

I compared `optimize.py` code of older, and newer versions, and noticed that in [this commit](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/81474eb34d99bba0b2908e35ba832ca735e40154) the initial stepsize is updated from

```
old_old_fval = old_fval + 5000
```

to

```
old_old_fval = None
```

I therefore tried changing the stepsize back to

```
old_old_fval = old_fval + 5000
```

and this time `fmin_bfgs` worked perfectly. I am guessing there might be an issue with the initial stepsize (`old_old_fval = None`) for `fmin_bfgs`, and this stepsize may not be flexible for all gradient sizes.

I am not really getting what's going on. Someone please help !

Comment: That message is just a warning, not a crash. Did the optimization actually converge on a sensible result?

Comment: Based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3581), a possible workaround might be to use `fmin_l_bfgs_b`

Comment: I am iterating 60 times, but the `fmin_bfgs` is crashing after 1st iteration.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that discussion, but I need to use `fmin_bfgs` only.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what sort of help you're asking for. You've identified the problem commit, you've read the discussion from the scipy developers, and you've found a way to circumvent the problem by editing the scipy source. As far as I can see, the only thing left to do is to write a more permanent patch to fix the problem in scipy, and that's something that would be best discussed on the scipy github page rather than on SO.

Comment: My company wants to use the latest version of scipy without the patch I figured out. Its important for us to not to go with the patch version for now, because in future versions we again may face the same problem. We are just trying to find whether this stepsize is really an issue or we need to fix something in our logitic regression algo. I have already discussed about this issue on github, but no body have replied yet.

Comment: There may well be ways to improve the stability of your logistic regression code such that it works with the new stepsize in `fmin_bfgs`, but I can't really comment unless you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's never going to be a totally solid guarantee that new versions of scipy won't change in such a way as to break your fitting code, so you should probably test for regressions yourself before switching to a newer version.